# I need a standard package to move key,value pairs over a net connection: any tips?

Tags: c, networking, open-source

As I hate reinventing the wheel, I wonder if there are any commonly used packaged out there for doing hte simple job of communicating (key,value) pairs of data betweeen two network endpoints (probably TCP/IP is the most likely carrier).  I would like something that works in any environment, which for me means Unix/Linux-style socket API written in C or maybe C++.  Java is nice, but only Java makes it hard to integrate into binary programs.  C# etc. is out due to the need to be portable to Linux hosts.

Is there such a beast?

Answer (score 5):

Consider using [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)? There are libraries available for most programming languages.

Comment: JSON is easy to decode in almost ANY language.. even if the Linux peer just saves it for something else to worry about. +1 , Good answer.

Answer (score 2):

Google has a data interchange format called [Procotol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) you may want to consider.

Comment: That also looks like a good candidate... except that maybe the need to declare things is a problem if you want to build a generic receiver end that muxes out data to various receivers. And you don't want to rebuild all every time.

Comment: I would guess that Protocol Buffers is (or can be made) much more efficient than JSON or YAML.

Comment: Can anyone say over-engineering?

Comment: Yes. MSI is over-engineered. Corba is over-engineered. Protocol Buffers is not.

Answer (score 1):

Socket-level APIs are the way to go if you want complete portability. I suppose there are packages for each language that can do the proper bit-molding in both directions, but I'm not aware of any single package that is ported to all these languages.

Answer (score 1):

[netstrings](http://cr.yp.to/proto/netstrings.txt) are an old solution if you would like to have minimal overhead.

Comment: Netstrings seems odd to me. The guy wrote a short paper describing how every C programmer transmits strings and then claims that they will secure the web? Am I missing something?

Comment: If you know the length of a string before you begin to process it you can prevent one major security exploit: buffer overruns.

Answer (score 0):

There's also [bencoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bencode).  There's probably libraries (torrent libraries) that will parse it easily enough.